# Не работает javascript в WebView на версии 4.0.3

Tags: android, javascript, webview

Пытаюсь загрузить страницу при помощи Webview. Создаю html код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Моя карта</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.api.2gis.ru/1.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Создаем обработчик загрузки страницы:
        DG.autoload(function () {
            // Создаем объект карты, связанный с контейнером:
            var myMap = new DG.Map('myMapId');
            // Устанавливаем центр карты, и коэффициент масштабирования:
            myMap.setCenter(new DG.GeoPoint(82.927810142519, 55.028936234826), 15);
            // Добавляем элемент управления коэффициентом масштабирования:
            myMap.controls.add(new DG.Controls.Zoom());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMapId" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

На версиях Андроида 2.1-2.3.3 прорабатывает идеально, но на версии 4.0.3 не удается загрузить страницу. Остается пустой Webview. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Странная проблема. На последней версии она должна еще круче чем на остальных отрабатывать. Советую проверить правильность установки библиотек и настроек.

Comment: Пробовали добавить в манифест пермишшен на доступ в сеть?

Comment: В манифесте все прописано. Один и тот же проект запускаю на устройствах с версиями 2.1 и 2.3.3 и работает. Тот же самый проект не работает на 4.0.3

Comment: @Мария_1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: проверил в эмуляторе 4.0.3. Через браузер страница грузится, карта отображается. Через phonegap загружаю loadurl, тоже все нормально. на реальном планшете тоже все работает (в обоих вариантах). ошибка где-то рядом, но не здесь.

Answer (score 1):

В общем это не баг, а фича, точнее исправленный баг. Дубльгис использует куки, которые для about:blank не устанавливаются, ибо не секьюрно.

Короче говоря, нужно заменить в вашем примере

```
WebView1_H.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
//Здесь первый параметр null эквивалентен базовому url about:blank
```

на что-то типа (можно дословно):

```
WebView1_H.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.example.com", html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Проверено в эмуляторе и на реальном девайсе.

Comment: То же касается localStorage. См. StackOverflow: [Android 4.0.1 breaks WebView HTML 5 local storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390985/android-4-0-1-breaks-webview-html-5-local-storage) и [android: Issue 16175](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16175).

Кстати почему вы грузите html через строку а не из asset'ов? так отлаживаться проще и удобнее...

Comment: Просто только начала разбираться со всем этим и пока пыталась простым путем все сделать, поэтому не лезла в asset's.

За ответ огромное спасибо) долго с этим мучалась)

Answer (score 0):

Если все так как вы описали - то тянет на выставление minor bug report. Выставить баг можно [здесь](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html). Очень похоже что ICS не хочет почему-то подгружать скрипт от внешнего источника http://maps.api.2gis.ru/1.0 (хотя он вроде доступен). Если баг подтвердится, то очень скоро вы получите ответ от разработчиков Android.

**P.S.** Надо все таки перепроверить на других устройствах. Было бы хорошо если бы скинули народу полные исходники.

Comment: Проверила на эмуляторе и на телефоне с андроидом 4.0.3. ниччего не получилось. Просто бежевый экранчик.

Вот исходники
http://depositfiles.com/files/frc4s53kw

Comment: @Мария_1 вечером если не забуду посмотрю и на эмуляторе и на ICS девайсе

Comment: буду ждать:)